# The Perfect Pair

Tags: c++, templates, stl, std-pair, stdtuple

Inspired by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37835248/c-stl-why-does-stdpair-expose-member-variables) I got thinking about what the perfect `std::pair` should look like. The compressed pair class (e.g. [boost's](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/utility/doc/html/compressed_pair.html)) provides a pair that is whose size is reduced when one of its types is an empty class. The compressed pair requires getters (`first()`, `second()`), to hide the fact that the member with an empty type doesn't exist.

Secondly, according to the [C++ docs](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/utility/pair/): "Pairs are a particular case of tuple", yet they're implemented as a separate class. Why not use partial template specializations, such as

```
template <typename ...Args> class tuple {};
template <typename T1, typename T2> class tuple<T1, T2> {}; // Implements a compressed pair
template <typename T1, typename T2> using pair = tuple<T1, T2>;
```

Further, to provide a more unified API one could overload `std::get` and `std::set` for `pair`, and ditch the `first()` and `second()` accessors. Or one could have both :)

### Questions

1. Why is `std::pair` not a specialization of `std::tuple`?
2. When might one use `std::pair` instead of a compressed pair? And even if there are cases, should the default be the compressed pair?
3. Why isn't there a compressed tuple class?

Comment: The answer to 1 is probably because [`std::pair`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair) was in the standard long before [`std::tuple`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple) was introduced in C++11.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Good point, however I don't think it would break backwards compatibility to rewrite `std::pair` as a specialization of `std::tuple`, leaving `first` and `second` exposed. Although perhaps this would cause more confusion than it's worth.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. `pair` predates `tuple` by good 10 years. It exist as a separate class mostly due to historical reasons and for backward compatibility. Making a breaking change to it is more trouble than it worth. If somebody wants tuple with two elements, they can just use tuple with two elements.
2. I have trouble coming with non-artificial examples, the only real reason I think is using standard library classes, and backward compatibility with code assuming `sizeof(pair<A,B>) >= sizeof(A) + sizeof(B)` and similar.
3. There is no `compressed_tuple` as `std::tuple` already performs EBO in every standard library implementation worth their salt.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've had a quick play with `tuple` and `pair` and here are [my results](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/00420f1a17d3b205). Interestingly, `pair` is never compressed and `tuple` is compressed on g++ and clang++. So am I correct in concluding: always use `tuple` instead of `pair`, unless you need no-compression? And msvc isn't worth its salt? :)

Comment: @Judge which version of msvc are you using? I believe, latest one has EBO for tuple. I rarely have the need for compressing that badly, and most of the time I interact with STL, so usually I use pair unless I have empty class and thousands of instances or total pair size would exceed register size/have more than 50% overhead due to aligment issues.

Comment: I'm using msvs 2015 Community edition (14.0.25123.00 update 2). Fair enough, but as a default surely compression can't hurt? Unless as you say, you're relying on the size of it.

Comment: @Judge Of course it cannot. I just use standard library + `auto`, so I have many pairs and lack of 2-element tuples. I do not care unless it is a bottleneck: I do not likely to reduce memory footprint or execution time noticeably otherwise. As for compiler: I cannot help with this. I do not use msvs, so I don't follow news about it. I might be a missing feature in compiler, or require specific flags, or something. I believe, standard library tuple is EBO enabled, though.

Comment: Ah my bad, I hadn't realized `tuple` wasn't in the STL. Ok, thank you - I'll do some digging into msvc compiler features.

Comment: @Judge Nah, it is there, STL nowdays relates to everything templated from C++ Standard Library due to [Metonymy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metonymy)

Comment: Sorry, I believe I misunderstood "... and lack of 2-element tuples." to mean you don't have access to `std::tuple`, which I assumed was because you were using the original [STL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Template_Library) instead of the standard library, my bad. Am I correct in understanding that you have a lot of `std::pairs` in your code, but not many `std::tuples` and you're fine without compression, and thus happy with `std::pair`?

Comment: @Judge "lack of 2-element tuples" _in my code_. Standard library usually takes and returns pairs, so I just use native types.

Comment: Anyone knows if there is any tuple compression with the gcc 6.2?